# Coldfusion Control Structures: Which IF does the else go to?

Tags: java, if-statement, coldfusion-8

In Java, the else statement goes to the closetest If statement.

so if you have a nested if statement:

```
if (expression) {

if(secExpression) {

}
else {
// goes with second expression
}
}
```

The else goes with the second if nested inside.

Where does the else go to in the Coldfusion control structure?

```
<cfif expression> 
   <cfif secExpression> 
   </cfif>
   <cfelse>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Your Java example is wrong -- because of the other braces there's not even a potential ambiguity. You'd better shorten it to something like `if (a) doA(); if (b) doB(); else doC();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested-tag syntax makes it unambiguous: The `<cfelse>` has to be inside of the `<cfif ...> ... </cfif>` tag, so in your example the `<cfelse>` can only be related to the outer `<cfif>`.